# rails gem error when starting server on port 80, use another port?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, webserver, port-number

I'm building a tablet app and my development environment is rails running ubuntu in a virualbox on windows host. I set a host-name of dev.myapp.com on the windows machine.

I run thin as my web-server, but when I run `sudo rails s thin -p 80` I get the error

```
Could not find multi_json-1.0.4 in any of the sources
```

installing the gem does not resolve the issue, and I get the same error if I run thin or not.

I think I was starting the server on a different port before, but I can't remember which it was. I've tried 8080, but that isn't working when I try to open `dev.myapp.com` in the browser on the host machine.

Any suggestions on either using another port (and which port works without needing a port extension), or resolving the multi_json error. Or other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing here was running with just a vanilla `rails s thin` and then pointing fiddler to redirect the ip address to port 3000

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `sudo` and run it like this `rails s thin -p 3000`.  Get this to work and verify that you can browse to http://dev.myapp.com:3000.  Once this is working you can re-introduce the sudo bit and revert to port 80.  Why sudo isn't finding the gem can't be answered without knowing more about your system.  Most likely a path issue, but there's too many variables to guess.

That all said.. what's the harm in running it on an alternate port?

Comment: Thanks Philip, there was never a problem running on port 3000 with the port specified or not. I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you say "what's the harm in running it on an alternate port?". 

When I run the app in the tablet, it tries to connect to the url, without the port number. I can't specify a port number in there due to the way backbone is making the requests, therefore, I need to be able to use only the domain. I'm not sure if that answers your question.